# GCC: how do I export (selected methods and) the vtable / typeinfo of a class without exporting the whole class?

Tags: c++, gcc, dllexport

I have this class in a shared library:

```
class Interface {
    int m_ref;
public:
    FOO_EXPORT virtual ~Interface();
    virtual void foo() = 0;

protected:
    void ref() { ++m_ref; }
    bool deref() { return --m_ref; }
};

// cpp file:
Interface::~Interface() {}
```

where `FOO_EXPORT` is `__attribute__((visibility=default))` for GCC and I'm compiling with `-fvisibiliy=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden`.

But when I use the `Interface` from another library, I get undefined references for typeinfo and vtable.

On MSVC, where `FOO_EXPORT` is `declspec(dllexport/dllimport`)`, this works fine, since the vtable is exported when a virtual function is exported.

I can of course export the whole class:

class FOO_EXPORT Interface {

But that exports all the inline methods, too.

Is there a middle ground which exports `~Interface()` and the vtable, but nothing else?

And if you know: why is GCC incompatible with MSVC?

Comment: `why is GCC incompatible with MSVC?` Because GCC/G++ and MSVC are different things?

Comment: MSVC++ also has the __declspec(novtable) attribute, should be used on interfaces since their vtable should never be used.  Only the vtable of the concrete class that implements the interface is used.  We can't see you doing this wrong in the client code, I'd guess you should make the constructor private so you get a better error message.

Comment: @HansPassant: Re: "vtable [of an interface] should never be used": I beg to differ: Say you have two interfaces like the one in OP above: `class InterfaceA; class InterfaceB;`. Then a valid use case of `dynamic_cast` is: `void foo(InterfaceB *ifaceB) { if (IfaceA * ifaceA = dynamic_cast<InterfaceA*>(ifaceB)) { /* object also implements InterfaceA */ } }`. And that is precisely why I need to export the vtable / typeinfo: without doing so, the cast may fail, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility "Problem with Exceptions" (same issue for dynamic casting).

Comment: That's RTTI, not vtable.  You are heading for the 3rd function, QueryInterface :)

Comment: There is an option called `-fvisibility-ms-compat` that should alleviate the issue.  However, it doesn't as of now: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55958

Comment: "But that exports all the inline methods, too" - I can not repro this, when I apply `FOO_EXPORT` to class and use `-fvisibility=hidden` inline methods aren't present in `.dynsym`. Please provide more details (`CFLAGS`, `readelf` command, etc.).